# Demand user's x509 certificate from java web application only when required

Tags: ssl, tomcat, x509

My web application authenticates the user based on user's x509 certificate.
For now, I've configured tomcat for mutual authentication by setting `"clientAuth=want"`.
However, as this certificate exchange happens during SSL handshake phase, I see following limitations with this approach:

1. All other applications deployed on the same tomcat also ask for
   user's certificate, which may not be necessary.
2. Whenever the first request is made to the server, it could be any
   public url such as css or img urls, the certificate pop-up comes on
   user's browser.
3. Javascript calls to my web application from any other app's UI,
   causes this pop-up on user's browser.
4. Once the https session is established, subsequent requests contain
   only end user's certificate and not the entire chain.

Is there any way using which I can negotiate with the browser and get user's certificate whenever my application needs it?

P.S. I already asked this question on stackoverflow, but no luck there, hence posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it won't work with HTTP/2 (which doesn't allow renegotiation) or TLSv1.3 (since the OpenJDK TLS 1.3 implementation does not support post handshake authentication).

What you will need to do is:

- remove `clientAuth="want"` from the connector
- configure the web application for `CLIENt-CERT` authentication
- configure security constraints to require authentication for any resource where
  you want to require a certificate
- optionally, use the AuthenticatedUserRealm (assuming you want to allow all users with valid certs)

Comment: What are the headers i will have to set in response to get the user's certificate? i.e. negotiate with the browser?

Comment: You don't need to set headers. The Servlet container will trigger (and handle) the TLS renegotiation and then expose the certificates via the standard request attributes (javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate and friends).

Comment: I am not quite sure if I got your point, Isn't clientAuth=false is doing the same thing?

Comment: clientAuth=want* i meant in last comment